# Why an IP address owned by Amazon would have an active connection to my Windows PC with an svchost.exe process?

Tags: windows, networking, netstat

Did a `netstat -fb`. One of the lines was:

```
[svchost.exe]
TCP    192.168.1.113:52683    server-13-32-253-84.sea19.r.cloudfront.net:https  CLOSE_WAIT
```

Server is registered to Amazon, a little confused. Why would an Amazon IP address be in a `svchost` process? Should I be concerned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svchost.exe` does a lot of things on Windows and hence needs to connect to various resources online. `tasklist /svc` may give you more information on the process, or see http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/view-resources-usage-each-service-svchost-windows-10/ for further help.

As your `netstat` output shows, the process was using an `https://` resource link to get data from this server.

So, just with that information, I do not think there is enough material to worry at all. You may find here: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-svchostexe-and-why-is-it-running/ a lot more information about `svchost.exe`.

If you go to https://server-13-32-253-84.sea19.r.cloudfront.net your browser will warn you there is a certificate mismatch. Indeed if you look into it: "The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.cloudfront.net, cloudfront.net". So this server is part of CloudFront architecture.

And since CloudFront is a big CDN provider it is not unusual to acquire resources from it, many companies use it.

As for the Amazon stuff: `server-13-32-253-84.sea19.r.cloudfront.net` resolves to `13.32.253.84` which is in this IP address block:

```
NetRange:       13.32.0.0 - 13.35.255.255
CIDR:           13.32.0.0/14
NetName:        AT-88-Z
NetHandle:      NET-13-32-0-0-1
Parent:         NET13 (NET-13-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Allocation
OriginAS:
Organization:   Amazon Technologies Inc. (AT-88-Z)
RegDate:        2016-08-09
Updated:        2016-08-09
Ref:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-13-32-0-0-1
...
```

So it just means this is a server of Amazon AWS/EC2 services, which is again nothing very unusual.